# One general contract for all or spawn new one for each instance?

Tags: dapp-development, dapps

What be the advantages vs. disadvantages or running a general contract or spawning a new one for each instance. Let say, that I am providing a contract so people can create their own crowdfunding. Every time that a new crowfunding is created with the contract, is it better to spawn a new contract with "new" keyword, with its own data structure. Or is it more practical to keep a general structure with all the crowdfunding instances?

In my application, there will not be an interaction between the different instances.

In your experience, what should one look for when taking this type of decision.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that spawning new instances is the ideal way to keep it simple. It will certainly make it more expensive to start an instance of crowdfunding which could be detrimental when gas prices are high.

A singleton doesn't have to be complex. You can consider separating concerns with a library that defines a Type, Crowdsale and primitive functions. This can give you decent readability within a contract that is meant to deal with them all.

Another advantage of a singleton would be the possibility of upgradeable logic that would get somewhat hairy with many instances.

Here's a little idea to help you think about using a library for data structure and simple methods:

```
pragma solidity 0.7.4;

// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed

library CrowdsaleLib {
    
    struct Crowdsale { // the "using" statement refers to this Type
        address owner;
        // this would contain the funders, targets, etc.
    }
    
    modifier onlyOwner(Crowdsale storage self) {
        require(msg.sender == self.owner, "You do not own this crowdsale");
        _;
    }
    
    function close(Crowdsale storage self) internal onlyOwner(self) {
        // implement the rules
        // do something to self, which is the complete instance state
    }
    
}

contract Crowdsalw {
    
    using CrowdsaleLib for CrowdsaleLib.Crowdsale;
    
    mapping(bytes32 => CrowdsaleLib.Crowdsale) crowdsales;
    
    function close(bytes32 crowdsaleId) public {
        CrowdsaleLib.Crowdsale storage c = crowdsales[crowdsaleId];
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do the (security) risks of managing assets like Ether or NFTs from different instances (crowdsales) in a singleton influence your take on this at all?

Comment: No, but the accounting might. I say "no" because the logic has to be secure in any case. A singleton would hold the ether for everyone and treat it as an internal accounting concern. Adding arbitrary tokens is a risk of its own in either case and you have to address it. Depending on what you are doing, you might find that using different contract addresses to hold assets is convenient. You might find it more gass-efficient to deploy little proxy contracts that share an implementation rather than deploying all the logic for each instance. Trade-offs.

Answer (score 0):

### Keep things as simple as possible

Most smart contracts rely on keeping things as simple as possible.

In that spirit, instantiating new contracts for each client is recommended as it reduces the required code / logic in the contract, as well as limits an attacker's surface to said contract.

And you also don't keep all your eggs ( ETH / Tokens / Value ) in one basket, which as a result will slow down contract drains if they do happen.

When talking about "crowd funding" you need different contracts meant to store "erc20 tokens" called "token trackers", so you're already doing it.

You also need to keep in mind that the logic that fits in one contract has to fit in the 8 mil gas limit, which for such a contract can be quite small.

### Real world example:

Maybe we're paranoid but the Crowd Funding DAO, we've been developing does take this to the extreme by creating **Personal Funding Vaults** for each contributing address to each separate crowd fund.

It's a smart contract that hardcodes 2 output and 2 controller addresses:

[See this github link for sourcecode](https://github.com/blockbitsio/smart-contracts/blob/master/contracts/Entity/FundingVault.sol)

Outputs:

1. One - The Vault Owner ( the wallet address that sent the eth )
2. Two - The Team Multi signature address

Controller:

1. One - The Funding Manager Smart Contract, that can request funds which then get sent to the "team" address, ( can happen only if all logic in the contract works as expected each and every time )
2. Two - The Vault Owner - Can request their funds back in case they do a "cash back"

Something like this would not really be reliable or even safe if you would stack multiple projects / addresses into one instance.

These vaults **do cost a lot**, but insure that no one else but **the team** or **the investor** can ever get the "value" out of it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across a similar issue working on a DAO project lately. I would encourage you to look at [DAOSTack Infra](https://github.com/daostack/infra) and [Alchemy](https://alchemy.daostack.io/), an UI for creating your DAO.

What is the goal you are aiming to achieve here? I believe its to save the most of gas fees you can save, since they are increasing and are abnormal at times. In the same time, I believe clients want to have a separate way to interact with their "own crowdfunding" contract.

Given that problem I think a hybrid solution might be best for your use case. Take all the functionality that is the same across clients and place that, as a data structure & logic under the `CrowdfundingLogic` which is only one contract instance for all clients, with separate data structures for each (ex, mapping / arrays / structs) and functions to interact with them.

Then create a lightweight, smaller `Controller_CLIENT_NAME` that can be deployed for every particular client with their access rights and any particular customizations. Have the controller inherit and interact with `CrowdfundingLogic` In this way you solve the problem by

1. minimizing gas usage
2. maximizing control, addressability and ownership

Let me know if you have any other concerns with your design